# Bash script wallpaper randomizer

Tags: bash, linux, awk

I thought it would be fun to write a simple and small bash script which randomly chooses a wallpaper from a given directory of a set of wallpaper images. The code is as follows.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# simple script to choose random image from
# Wallpaper directory and set it as desktop background

# cd into Wallpaper dir

cd /home/user/Pictures/Wallpapers

# using nano time mod # of imgs in Wallpapers (+1 b/c awk fields start at ind 1) 
# to provide a semi-random field number for the awk statement

RAND=$(($(date +%N) % $(ls -h | wc -l) + 1))
IMG=$(ls -h | awk -v r=$RAND 'BEGIN{FS = "\n"; RS = ""} {print $r}')

# change the desktop with the img file provided from the awk statement
# (the way to set the background is system dependent but the gist is the same)

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/user/Pictures/Wallpapers/$IMG"
```

This is really just a small, fun project, but I am almost certain I am not doing this the most efficient way, so any feedback would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Why you shouldn't parse ls.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Let's consider `ls` bad practice, and allow me to introduce a different method to solve your issue all together. Find every *file* in the directory, /home/user/Pictures/Wallpapers, perform a random sort on it and then grab the first result.

`find /home/user/Pictures/Wallpapers -type f | sort -R | head -1`

[Sort man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html)

```
       -R, --random-sort
              shuffle, but group identical keys.  See shuf(1)
```